# How add guild user Discord

Tags: python, django, discord

I try add member on guild

[documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member)

My code:

views.py

```
def login(request):
template = loader.get_template('login.html')
code = request.GET.get('code')
at = Oauth.get_access_token(code)
user_json = Oauth.get_user_json(at)
id_user = user_json.get('id')
invite = Oauth.join_server(id_user).get('message')
context = {
    'code': code,
    'access_token': at,
    'id_user': id_user,
    'invite': invite,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Oauth.py

```
 @staticmethod
 def join_server(user_id):
    guild_id = 'guild_id'
    url = f'{Oauth.discord_api_url}/guilds/{guild_id}/members/{user_id}'
    bot = 'token_bot'
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {bot}",
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               }
    link = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
    return link
```

I get error:

1. {'message': '405: Method Not Allowed', 'code': 0}
2. {'message': 'Unknown Member', 'code': 10007}

how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The docs state that you should use the method `PUT`, instead of `GET`. I don't believe this is going to fix It all, but It's a start.